# How to iterate in a Rust element non-iterable?

Tags: for-loop, rust, iterator, rust-cargo

I'm trying to iterate trough the results of this variable created from an API with a for loop (here commented or it will give an error):

```
    let create_account_instruction: Instruction = solana_sdk::system_instruction::create_account(
    &wallet_pubkey,
    &mint_account_pubkey,
    minimum_balance_for_rent_exemption,
    Mint::LEN as u64,
    &spl_token::id(),
    );
    println!("Creating the following instructions: {:?}", create_account_instruction);

    // for x in create_account_instruction {
    //     println!("{:?}", x)
    // }
```

Here is the results I would like to iterate trough (FYI: Those private and public keys are just for test on devnet):

```
Creating the following instructions: Instruction { program_id: 11111111111111111111111111111111, accounts: [AccountMeta { pubkey: ESCkgk5AfDC8cXd4KYjkUda1psCL8otfu8NvniUBiGhX, is_signer: true, is_writable: true }, AccountMeta { pubkey: Ah63GoKnnBicTELvfz2F9YvF9vaR51HR2BK3hJWwWE8x, is_signer: true, is_writable: true }], data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 77, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 221, 246, 225, 215, 101, 161, 147, 217, 203, 225, 70, 206, 235, 121, 172, 28, 180, 133, 237, 95, 91, 55, 145, 58, 140, 245, 133, 126, 255, 0, 169] }
```

If I try to iterate trough it via for loop (uncommenting the above), I get this error:

```
Compiling AmatoRaptor v0.1.0 (/home/joomjoo/Desktop/Tester)
error[E0277]: `Instruction` is not an iterator
--> src/main.rs:89:14
|
89  |     for x in create_account_instruction {
|              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Instruction` is not an iterator
|
= help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `Instruction`
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `Instruction`
note: required by `into_iter`
--> /home/joomjoo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/collect.rs:234:5
|
234 |     fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain
```

My question is what is the easiest way to iterate trough the results?

Comment: What are the "results"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Solana documentation](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/1.7.12/solana_sdk/instruction/struct.Instruction.html), `Instruction` is a struct:

```rust
pub struct Instruction {
    pub program_id: Pubkey,
    pub accounts: Vec<AccountMeta, Global>,
    pub data: Vec<u8, Global>,
}
```

You can access its attributes, and iterate over them:

```rust
for x in create_account_instruction.data {
    ...
}
```

or

```rust
for x in create_account_instruction.accounts {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried with both, however it's requesting me to add a borrowing with "&", so like: for x in &create_account_instructions.account..., but this will only itereate inside the specific part called (either .data or .account), is there anyway to iterate trough all the items in that struct? (so for instance to get also the program_id).

Comment: @SkylerX, that is entirely imposible, since they are not even the same type. What is what you really want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to print out all the elements in that struct, rather then have them print out all together, as it's very difficult to read and debug, so I am trying to find a way to print them out with some order one by one from top to bottom, rather then a very long print out on multiple lines.

Comment: @SkylerX, you can implement `Display` for some wrapper over the type (since you cannot impl anything for a foreign type). But you will have to do it manually for each of the fields anyway.